# Data Transformation WS02

Tags: loops, wso2, esb, data-mapping, wso2-esb

I have the following XML coming from a Database query and need to send the result to an API call. But I want to transform data in a different format, how do I do that. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Result from Database:

```
    `<Data>  
      <User Name="XYZ">
        <DETAILS>
           <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
           <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
           <SUBJECT>COMPUTER SCIENCE<SUBJECT>         
         </DETAILS>
       </User>
       <User Name="XYZ">
        <DETAILS>
           <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
           <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
           <SUBJECT>INFO SCIENCE<SUBJECT>         
       </DETAILS>
      </User>
     </Data> `
```

How I need to Transform: 
         `<Data>

         <User Name="XYZ">
          <DETAILS>
             <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
             <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
             <SUBJECT>COMPUTER SCIENCE<SUBJECT>
            </DETAILS>
             <DETAILS>
             <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
              <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
              <SUBJECT>INFO SCIENCE<SUBJECT>

             </DETAILS>
            </User>
          </Data>`

Comment: Second sample is not valid xml

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, like your xslt transformation. That way people know what you have tried so far and they can give you a better answer.

Comment: I have not tried using xslt transformation. I was guessing If i can do that using foreach loop or iterate or script mediators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEach mediator is for transforming segments of data and replacing them in the original payload. Iterate mediator is not used for transformations as such. It is used for calling backends and aggregating responses. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ForEach+Mediator for more details.

From the sample you have added here, seems like you need to merge results by the username. Hence you cannot use ForEach, Iterate mediators. However, you can use Script mediator, but it is better to use XSLT mediator since it is a direct and easy XML manipulation.

Comment: Thanks XSLT Mediator did the job!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have unique User with attribute in message. If there is User with Name="XYZ" that guarantees that document doesn't contain any another User with attribute Name!="XYZ"

You can use next xslt transformation

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(User[last()])}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="User/@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="User/*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make a few changes to accommodate my data.. and the xslt mediator worked fine!